# Как удалить кнопки управления Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Использую gmaps.js. Без проблем есть возможность добавить маркеры, выделить область и тд.

**Как я могу удалить кнопки управления (*Zoom +-*, надпись *Google* и кнопку *FullScreen*)?**

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой css подобрал для этого:

```
div#map a,
div#map button,
div.gm-bundled-control div.gmnoprint {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[рабочий код](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/QoJBVX)

PS: почему-то сниппет `gmaps.js` тут не работает